# How to get username and password from query list in spring and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to validate whether this is registered user or not by checking its value from database using Spring MVC and Hibernate. i really don't know how to do this I have searched lot of sites but didn't get the solution.

My Bean class is

```
    package net.codejava.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phno;
    private String address;

    public String getPhno() {
        return phno;
    }

    public void setPhno(String phno) {
        this.phno = phno;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

My Dao class is

```
 package net.codejava.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

public interface UserDAO {
    public List<User> list();

    public User get(int id);

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user);

    public void delete(int id);
```

}

My DaoImpl class is

```
    package net.codejava.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserDAOImpl() {

    }

    public UserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> list() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(User.class)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

        return listUser;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        User userToDelete = new User();
        userToDelete.setId(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(userToDelete);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User get(int id) {
        String hql = "from User where id=" + id;
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();

        if (listUser != null && !listUser.isEmpty()) {
            return listUser.get(0);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

My Main Controller class Method which is giving me list of users is

```
  @RequestMapping("/list")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception {
        List<User> listUsers = userDao.list();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserList");
        model.addObject("userList", listUsers);


        return model;
    }
```

Here I want a method which provide me the username and password so that I can validate them.Please forgive me but I have searched not found any good solution

Comment: Do you want Username and Password from view ?

Comment: No i want username and password from database so that I can check them at my login page

Comment: You already have `listUsers`, you can use it to get Username and Password.

Comment: I really don't know how will i use it because I am new to Spring and Hibernate

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring and Hibernate. Iterate the List `listUsers` and call the `getPassword()` method for each `User` object.